# Cual sería la forma más optima de crear un mapa clave/valor (dict, HashMap, Map, una tabla sql con primary key, etc) en un archivo binario

Tags: lenguaje-agnóstico

Quería guardar la información en formato clave-valor en un archivo, usando una cadena como clave. Ejemplo:

```
cadena1 -> 1
cadena2 -> 2
```

Pero no conozco exactamente el algoritmo que usan tipicamente este tipo de mapeos para ser de complejidad O(1)

Lo más cercano que se me ocurre es crear tantos registros como hashcodes existentes pueda haber, y, si un string `string` tiene el hash `hash` agregar el valor en la fila `hash`, permitiendo que, obtener el código hash de `string`, se sepa de una que fila tiene el valor. Ciertamente, este algoritmo implicaría un archivo bastante pesado.

Finalmente, me disculpo si las etiquetas no son las adecuadas, y se que esto no es unicamente de Python, Java y Javascript. Invito a cualquier usuario a editar las etiquetas o indicarme cuales son las correctas.

**Edit:**

Pruebas en Python con el siguiente código:

```
import sys

dct = dict()

print(sys.getsizeof(dct))
dct["hola"] = "mundo"
print(sys.getsizeof(dct))
dct["adios"] = "mundo"
print(sys.getsizeof(dct))
dct["color"] = "mundo"
print(sys.getsizeof(dct))
```

Me indican que el tamaño del diccionario se define unicamente una vez se agrega el primer item y se mantiene invariable sin importar que se agreguen más, lo que me da la impresión de que mi idea anterior es el algoritmo habitual.

¿Es este el algoritmo más adecuado, o hay uno más eficiente?

Comment: ¿Tiene que ser un solo archivo? Porque podría ser un único directorio que contenga archivos con nombre el hash y el contenido del archivo sería el valor del item. Ese directorio luego se podría comprimir en un zip.

Comment: @ordago no se como no pensé en eso! Gracias por la idea! Aun así, me interesaría ver la respuesta sobre el tema, la cual podría ser util para otros.

Comment: @ordago Pregunta, el formato zip usa un sistema de tipo clave-valor, de complejidad o(1)?

Comment: Mis pruebas indican que accede rapidamente al archivo 100.000

Comment: Existen librerías que te podrían ayudar como [deephash](https://zepworks.com/deepdiff/5.6.0/deephash.html) o [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html), aunque no se que tan eficiente sea a diferencia de escribir un programa adecuado para la tarea.

Comment: La etiqueta que no corresponde es [programación-bajo-nivel] @DanteS., ya que se refiere a lenguajes como _ensamblador_. Si estás buscando que la respuesta no sea solo en Python, podrías usar [lenguaje-agnóstico].

Comment: @padaleiana Muchas gracias por la sugerencia, ya lo cambio :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En lo referente a la implementación difiere en cada lenguaje aunque la idea general detrás de las tablas hash es la misma. En realidad puedes implementar tablas hash usando casi cualquier estructura para almacenar los datos, desde arrays, vectores, arboles binarios o incluso archivos...

Dado que mencionas Python y sus `dict`s... En el caso concreto de Python (Python >= 3.7), a muy grandes rasgos, la implementación es la siguiente:

- Un diccionario consta por debajo de dos arrays en memoria, un *sparce* array y un *dense* array.

  - El *dense array* contiene instancias de una estructura C con tres campos, el hash y las dos direcciones de memoria de los objetos que conforma cada clave y su valor. Los nuevos items se agregan al final del array en orden de inserción, por esto los diccionarios en Python >= 3.7 mantienen el orden de inserción.
  - El *disperse array* es el que verdaderamente hace la "magia" de la tabla hash. Almacena los indices del segundo array donde esta almacenado cada item del diccionario.
- La idea principal detrás de toda tabla hash es que a través del hash se obtiene un indice valido en la tabla, el array. Esto hace que buscar un item sea muy eficiente dado que en principio se reduce a calcular el hash, obtener el indice e indizar sobre un array. Digo "en principio" porque en la vida real hay que lidiar con las colisiones como veremos después.

### Agregar entrada al diccionario

Cuando agregas una nueva clave a un diccionario, en esencia lo que ocurre es lo siguiente:

1. Se calcula el hash de la clave.
2. Al hash se le aplica una mascara que permite obtener un indice valido para el array interno. Por ejemplo, `hash & (dic_size - 1)`.
3. Con nuestro indice obtenido nos vamos al array (en el caso de Python este es el *sparce array*) y indizamos sobre el.

   - Si en esa posición no hay nada, se agrega una nueva entrada al final del `dense array` con los datos mencionados arriba  y su indice se agrega al *sparce array*.
   - Si en esa posición ya hay algo significa que o bien la clave ya existe en el diccionario (por lo que simplemente se reescribiría) o tenemos una colisión de hash (dos claves distintas generan el mismo hash y por tanto el mismo indice).

     Si es una colisión no podremos almacenar la nueva clave en esa posición, pero en algún sitio tendremos que hacerlo. En Python se usa [direccionamiento abierto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_addressing) para lidiar con las colisiones, básicamente se aplica un sistema de `probing`, se calcula un nuevo indice para la clave hasta que se genera un indice del array que no contiene nada. En los diccionarios de Python se usa un *probing* pseudoaleatorio con el fin de aumentar las posibilidades de encontrar un indice disponible cuanto antes y disminuir el agrupamiento, mientras es aun predecible, lo cual es esencial para replicar el *probing* al buscar la clave luego.

Es fácil darse cuenta que un problema de este algoritmo es que cuanto mas lleno este el array mas fácil es que se generen colisiones, es decir que hash + mask genere un indice ya ocupado. Para disminuir esta posibilidad lo que se hace es impedir que el diccionario este a mas de 2/3 de su capacidad. Cuando el array tiene ocupados mas de dos tercios de sus indices disponibles se redimensiona, si ampliamos un poco tu ejemplo podemos ver esto en acción:

```
import sys


dct = dict()

print(f"0 --> {sys.getsizeof(dct)}")
for i, key in enumerate(map(str, range(100))):
    dct[key] = ""
    print(f"{i + 1} --> {sys.getsizeof(dct)}")
```

> ```
> 0 --> 64
> 1 --> 184
> ...
> 5 --> 184
> 6 --> 272
> ...
> 10 --> 272
> 11 --> 464
> ...
> 21 --> 464
> 22 --> 832
> ...
> 42 --> 832
> 43 --> 1584
> ...
> 85 --> 1584
> 86 --> 3328
> ...
> ```

Sin tener en cuenta la posibilidad de colisiones, la idea esquemáticamente seria algo como:

> ```
> >>> dicc["foo"] = "hola"
>
> hash("foo") = 100010101
> hash & mask = 2 ╗
>                 ║
>                 v
> ╔══════╦══════╦═══╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╗
> ║ Null ║ Null ║ 0 ║ Null ║ Null ║ Null ║ Null ║ Null ║ Sparce array
> ╚══════╩══════╩═══╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╝
>                 ║
>                 v
> ╔═════════════════════════╗
> ║ Struct{                 ║
> ║   hash: 100010101       ║
> ║   key:  0x7f6dc42cfef0  ║ Dense array
> ║   value: 0x6bedd420ace2 ║
> ║ }                       ║
> ╚═════════════════════════╝
>
> >>> dicc["bar"] = "mundo"
>
> hash("bar") = 110100010
> hash & mask = 5 ══════════════════╗
>                                   ║
>                                   v
> ╔══════╦══════╦═══╦══════╦══════╦═══╦══════╦══════╗
> ║ Null ║ Null ║ 0 ║ Null ║ Null ║ 1 ║ Null ║ Null ║
> ╚══════╩══════╩═══╩══════╩══════╩═══╩══════╩══════╝
>                 ║                 ║
>                 v                 v
> ╔═════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╗
> ║ Struct{                 ║ Struct{                 ║
> ║   hash: 100010101       ║   hash: 110100010       ║
> ║   key:  0x7f6dc42cfef0  ║   key:  0x7f6dc42cfe30  ║
> ║   value: 0x6bedd420ace2 ║   value: 0x7f6dc590b0b0 ║
> ║ }                       ║ }                       ║
> ╚═════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╝
> ```

### Búsqueda en el diccionario

A la hora de buscar una clave en el diccionario se procede de forma similar:

- Se calcula el hash
- Se aplica la mascara para obtener el indice
- Se indiza con el sobre el *sparce array*:

  - Si en ese indice no hay nada se genera un `KeyError`
  - Si contiene un indice al *dense array* se indiza sobre el y se procede a comprobar si la clave es la misma que la almacenada en la estructura, para ello se hace lo siguiente:

    ```
    clave_buscada is clave_almacenada or
        hash(clave_buscada) == hash_almacenado
            and clave_buscada == clave_almacenada
    ```

    Primero se comprueba la identidad porque es muy eficiente y se asume que si dos objetos tienen la misma identidad es que son iguales. Si la id no coincide, aun pueden ser la misma clave almacenada como dos objetos distintos, por lo que se comprueba el hash, si no coincide sabemos que son distintas claves, pero si coincide pueden ser la misma o no (colisión de hash), por lo que pasamos a comprobar si las claves son iguales mediante el método mas certero pero mas ineficiente, aplicar el operador de igualdad.

  Si al final resulta que la clave coincide, retorna su valor. Si no coincide iniciamos el `probing` hasta encontrar otro indice en el que la clave coincida (aplicando el paso anterior a cada nuevo indice) o este vacío, si damos con un indice vacío durante el *probing* entonces la clave definitivamente no existe en el diccionario y se genera el KeyError.

### Eliminar clave del diccionario

Para eliminar una clave del diccionario no basta con eliminar la entrada en el *dense array* y establecer el indice a `null` en el *sparce array*. La razón es que si hacemos esto las claves almacenadas usando el `probing` partiendo de ese indice serán inaccesibles. Lo que se hace es reemplazar los datos originales por un dummmy, de forma que el *probing* siga funcionando para las búsquedas pero la posición queda marcada de forma que pueda reutilizarse e insertarse una nueva clave en el si es necesario.

Si alguien le interesa el tema y no tienes demasiados problemas con el ingles, hay una [charla de Raymond Hettinger en la PyCon 2017](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=npw4s1QTmPg) en la que explica algo mas detalladamente lo que comento yo e incluso implementa una [versión simplificada de un diccionario en Python puro](https://gist.github.com/righthandabacus/a0f1546bc23e8fb36cbfc4ddffc6298b) (obviamente `dict` en CPython se implementa en C).

---

Volviendo a la pregunta, podrías implementar el mismo algoritmo que usa Python sustituyendo los arrays por ficheros, teniendo en cuenta las diferencias entre indizar/modificar un array en memoria a hacer algo similar con un archivo.

O también puedes hacer cosas mas simples como la que te sugiere ordago en su comentario, **solo ten siempre en cuenta una cosa cuando trabajas con tablas hash o hashes en general, que existe siempre la posibilidad de colisiones (dos claves, mismo hash) y debes manejarlas de alguna manera, es matemáticamente imposible que una función hash por buena que sea carezca de colisones**. La elección de una buena función hash que minimice las colisiones es un paso muy importante para la eficiencia de cualquier implementación de una tabla hash, así como el manejo de las colisiones cuando estas se producen. En la misma dirección, si la seguridad es importante, las colisiones pueden ser usadas por un atacante, Python mitiga esto randomizando la función hash en cada ejecución, de forma que una misma clave no genere siempre el mismo hash entre ejecuciones.

Comment: Pareciera un sistema muy similar al que planteé en la pregunta. Y al ser solo números, no se requieren muchos bytes para representarlos, haciendo un supuesto archivo más liviano. Al final, decidí usar sqlite3, pero tu respuesta me sirvió para aprender un poco más, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

No podría escribir un algoritmo optimo para almacenar esa información para archivos grandes, por lo menos usando **`Python`** deberías de manejar el limite de memoria para los diccionarios ya que podrías usar la librería **hashlib** que te facilita diferentes opciones para pasar la información en formato `json`.

```
import hashlib
import json

sha1 = hashlib.sha1()
d = {}

d["ejemplo"] = 1
sha1.update(json.dumps(d).encode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: Es bueno ver la alternativa. Sin embargo, busco guardar eso en un archivo binario. De cualquier forma, lo resolví "compilando" un directorio en una base de datos sqlite. Aún así, espero otras respuestas por simple curiosidad y aprendisaje. Gracias igual por la idea.